# Find difference between two queries in Grafana influxdb

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I am trying to find difference between 2 query results.

Query 1 : has time, state (from select query)
Query 2 : has state (from show tag values)

**Query 1**
[image]

**Query 2**
[image]

However, the difference is not showing the right results, even the individual fields are not populating all the state names.

**Transformation**
[image]

can someone please provide some guidance here.

Comment: Check the the transformation doc. There is no defined how timeseries (query 1) and non timeseries (query 2) should have defined binary operation.

Comment: @janGaraj do you mean this is not possible?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible when you use timeseries and non timeseries. It can be possible with timeseries and timeseries (but then is time dimension in the place as well).
https://community.grafana.com/t/addition-of-queries-via-expression-option-not-working/112256/2